# Strategy to win game if players can take upto 4 coins

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Two players are playing a game in which each have to pick 1, 2, 3 or 4 coins in each turn. There are n coins in total. The player who picks up the last coin, he wins. Design a strategy to win the game.

What would be the algorithmic strategy to solve the problem so that I can win the game assuming I am one of the players?

Comment: We have no win condition.

Comment: There is no solution to laziness.. Unfortunately.

Comment: @erip - how can you say that?

Comment: Because, while I assume "You win if the opponent takes the last coin" or "You win if you take the last coin" would be the win condition; but your post states no such thing.

Comment: Well, sorry that I didn't specify it. But to win you have to choose the last coin.

Comment: You tell us to design a strategy to win the game, and you want to maximize your winning chance. Let's make a rule that, If there's only 1 coin left, it's your turn to go. Then how would you lose?

Answer (score 8):

Make a table for first 10 or so games; there will be a clear pattern. If there is...

```
1 coin: take 1, you win
2 coins: take 2, you win
3 coins: take 3, you win
4 coins: take 4, you win
5 coins: you lose (whatever you choose, the opponent wins by rule 1-4)
6 coins: take 1, opponent loses by rule 5
7 coins: take 2, opponent loses by rule 5
...
10 coins: you lose (whatever you choose, the opponent wins by rule 6-9)
11 coins: take 1, opponent loses by rule 10
...
```

So, you always take `n % 5` coins, unless it is `0` (if it's `0`, you lose with perfect play from opponent whatever you do, so take 1 to maximise his chances of making a mistake).